# How to prove a statement regarding divisibility?

Tags: logic, divisibility

I want to prove that: $∀r,s∈N,r<s∧r>0⇒s∤r$

I'm thinking of rewriting this as a contrapositive along with a translation of the divides predicate:

$∀r,s∈N,∃k∈Z,r=sk⇒r≥s∨r≤0$

Where would I go from here, assuming that the contrapositive was the right way to go?

Comment: If s|r then r=ks for some positive integer k.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Yes, $k \ge 1$ so......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second statement, if $r$ is not positive then we are done.  Else, $k>0$ since $s$ is positive too.  Then $k\geq 1$ so $r=ks\geq 1\cdot s = s$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe proceed by contradiction: assume $s\mid r$, then $r=sk$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. Since we have $r>0$, we must have $k>0$, so $sk>0$ (note, $s\neq 0$ since $0\nmid r>0$).

> Well this produces our contradiction, since we also suppose $r<s$, so we have $$r=sk\geq s>r$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach this: try and simplify $\;s \mid r\;$ after expanding its definition, under the assumption that $\;0<r<s\;$.

In this answer I'm assuming all variables range over the integers.

So we calculate as follows: $%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
%$ 
$$\calc
    s \mid r
\op\equiv\hint{definition of 'divides'}
    \langle \exists k :: ks=r \rangle
\op\then\hint{using assumption $\;0<r<s\;$}
    \langle \exists k :: 0<ks<s \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{divide by $\;s\;$, using $\;s>0\;$}
    \langle \exists k :: 0<k<1 \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{$\;k\;$ is an integer}
    \false
\endcalc$$
In other words, we've proved
$$
\langle \forall r,s :: 0<r<s \;\then\; s \not\mid r \rangle
$$

$%
\endgroup
%$